# XML errors with gridlayout

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to run this but it keeps giving me errors. Is it possibly in import problem?
XML using grid layout gives me the following errors

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    app:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:useDefaultMargins="true" 
    app:columnCount="1" >

<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/from_label"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/from"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/from"  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"  
        android:completionThreshold="3" />  

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/to_label"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/to"
        android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/to"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:completionThreshold="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/load_directions"
        app:layout_columnSpan="@integer/create_account_pane_column_count"
        app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/load_directions" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Errors:
At the very start:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - error: No resource identifier found for 
     attribute 'columnCount' in package 
     'com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock'
    - error: No resource identifier found for 
     attribute 'useDefaultMargins' in package 
     'com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock'
    - error: No resource identifier found for 
     attribute 'alignmentMode' in package 
     'com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock'
    - error: No resource identifier found for 
     attribute 'orientation' in package 
     'com.ecs.google.maps.v2.
```

Further down:

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_gravity' 
     in package 'com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock'
```

This gives me an error reading R which I assume is because this does not link up properly with the XML for whatever reason.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <!-- Specify the correct minSDK and targetSDK versions. -->
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <!-- Google Maps related permissions -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network connectivity permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Access Google based webservices -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- External storage for caching. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- My Location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

`    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyA_u1faIXRhx_Q7NafFbrhQJEerl6UUbPY"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.actionbarsherlock.TabbedActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.ecs.google.maps.v2.fragment.DirectionsInputActivity"
            android:label="@string/directions_input" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do not think this is multiple errors but rather one big error which is messing with everything.